# Coldfusion and php, in the same file?

Tags: php, coldfusion

On this server, I can use both .cfm and .php files.  Both types will be parsed, as expected.

However, I want .cfm files to be parsed for php, as well.  For example,

```
//test.cfm:
<cfoutput>hello from cf</cfoutput>    
<?php echo 'hello from php'; ?>
// outputs the php, verbatim, without processing :(
```

I know that I can change the php config, to parse .cfm.  I dont know what order the parsing will take place or any other pros and cons, tricks and tips.

The goal here is that I want to wrap php (which i know well) into a cfm file (much less experience).  The cfm file will be in an admin section, which automatically checks the user auth, and includes other cf files.

So, it seems to me that if coldfusion parses the file (checking the user-auth and all that), then hands it over to php, that would be the process that I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think this is possible or at least practical. If you need to use both languages, it would be best to output the information using PHP into something else you can work with, like a POST/GET request or JSON, then handle that info with CFML... or vice versa.

Comment: I wouldn't mix CF with PHP. Easier, faster and more elegant way is to use only one of these languages in certain areas of your website.

Comment: This could, quite possibly, be the most Rube Goldberg-ish way of approaching web application development I have ever heard. It would be easier to just learn ColdFusion.

Answer (score 1):

This has been done:

See: http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/projects/cfgroovy2/

Most of the documentation has mixing ColdFusion and Groovy, but other languages can be mixed in too.

Example code:

```
<cfimport prefix="g" taglib="engine" />

...

<h2>Run some PHP (via Quercus)</h2>
<cftry>
   <g:script lang="php">
      <?php
      $variables["myArray"][] = "Pretty Happy People wrote PHP.";
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump($variables["myArray"]);
      echo "</pre>";
      ?>
   </g:script>
   <cfcatch type="CFGroovy.UnknownLanguageException">
     <p>Quercus needs to be added to your classpath for the PHP example to work</p>
   </cfcatch>
   <cfcatch type="any">
     <p>Error running PHP code: #cfcatch.message#</p>
     <p>#cfcatch.detail#</p>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Source: https://ssl.barneyb.com/svn/barneyb/cfgroovy2/trunk/demo/index.cfm

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the ColdFusion Application Server, what it supports and what level of interoperability you want. Generally if you want to be able to mix variables across statements, then you need to share the ColdFusion pageContext and make sure that php variables are written and updated. I don't believe that the example above does this, but I am happy to stand corrected. The other alternative is to called ColdFusion from PHP, again using Quercus. These 2 articles will help you do this. The first shows how to call Java from PHP, the second how to call ColdFusion from Java.

http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#Instantiatingobjectsbyclassname
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffb.html

Firstly create a ColdFusion component that can render ColdFusion dynamically

```
<cfcomponent displayname="ColdFusion renderer" output="false"> 
    <cffunction name="render" returntype="'String' or 'Any'">
    <!---
    Do something with the coldfusion code here e.g:

    write to a file using <CFFILE> and then <CFMODULE> or <CFINCLUDE>,<CFSAVECONTENT> it 

    or if the ColdFusion is all script, use the evaluate() function

    --->
    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

the invoke the component in PHP, via Java, using the CFCProxy

```
<?php
function cfml($code)
{
    $cfc = new Java("coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy", "path/to/cfc/above");
    $cfc.render($code);
}

echo 'hello from php';

cfml(<<<EOT
    <cfoutput>Hello from CF</cfoutput>
EOT
);
?>
```

Comment: I need to have the php *in* the .cfm.  The reason is, /admin/somefile.cfm triggers the user auth, which is already in place. So, if the user is allowed to get a file.cfm from the /admin dir, great, otherwise, user will be redirected to login.cfm.  This infrastructure is already inplace.  Now that the user is vetted for somefile.cfm, I need php to parse it.  I dont need to share any variables, or anything like that.  the only reason for all this is to piggy-back on the existing user-auth.

Comment: sounds like the php in coldfusion using Quercus approach is the best solution